# How can I convert a String type to ConveyorPath type?

Tags: anylogic

I wish to convert a String type to a ConveyorPath type but it seems that only the other way round is possible. For example, I am simply converting "blueConveyor" to blueConveyor.

I understand that i can simply use a function like this:
[image]

However, i have many conveyors (about 60), which means it might be very inefficient for my code.

What are some other feasible methods that can be used that is more efficient than a switch structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select all your  60 conveyors and add them all to a collection (right click and select as below). Make sure to select the conveyors indvidually, not accidentially select the network they belong to):
[image]

Make sure the collection looks like this:
[image]

Then loop across the collection in your function (first, change the input argument to be a String named "myInputName"):

```
for (ConveyorPath currentConveyor : myCollection) {
    if (currentConveyor.getName().equals(myInputName)) {
        return currentConveyor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works but there was sort of a bug. The error comes out when i delete the portion of code circled in red: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RazRwe9Hvq_c3Cw7Tj5xTxfhviypded0

What am i missing out here?

Comment: well, the bottom line has no idea what "BayMout" is, I would assume. It should really be "return null"